# $PATH not working

Tags: paths

How can this happen?

```
    jon@vaio:~/brickify$ /usr/bin/node -v
    v0.8.11
    jon@vaio:~/brickify$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
    jon@vaio:~/brickify$ node -v
    jon@vaio:~/brickify$
```

`/usr/bin` is in `$PATH`, so just writing `node -v` should work the same as writing `/usr/bin/node -v`

Comment: Does `node` exist in any other folder on the path?

Comment: `which node` will show you the path of the binary that's actually running when you do `node` without an absolute path. Like ObsessiveFOSS says, it's likely there's another `node` in the directories before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Is that dollar sign at the end of your path really there, or was it some sort of typo?  It shouldn't actually be there, but if it is, it may cause problems with your path.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSO: yes, it also exists in `/usr/sbin`...
When I run `/usr/sbin/node -v` I get the same lack of output as when I run `node -v`. So that explains. But, why the node installation chose to set things up this way, still puzzles me. But that's another question.
@roadmr: `which node` points to `/usr/bin`
@MartyFried: The dollar sign was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see which version of a program is being invoked by using the which command, e.g.

```
which node
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games$
```

You have to remove the $ sign from end oth the PATH value

Comment: This was a typo, sorry